# Event Created Through API not Visible on Google Calendar App

Tags: python, android, google-calendar-api

I am creating calendar events with Python in a shared Google calendar. Up to a few days ago, everything worked fine, but suddendly I am not seeing the events created through Google Calendar API on mobile devices anymore.

The events are still showing up in the web interface and I can access the events through API.

I assumed that there are syncinc issues between the app and, but whenever I create an event manually in the calendar (web interface), it automatically pops up on the mobile app. The issue occurs with two Android phones.

Comment: Are you sure the events from this Calendar are visible in the mobile app? Maybe you are logged into another account that doesn't have this Calendar, or where it's not set as visible?

Comment: Yes, the calendar is visible in the mobile app. Manually created events within the same calendar appear on all devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you problem is for allday events, then I just encountered the same problem: via the API I generate allday events, with start date = end date. It was working last fall, and as in your case now they appear on the Web interface, and not on the mobile app.
I dragged one such event to another date on the Web interface, and then it appeared on the mobile. Then, I examined the event under debugger from my code(php in my case), and I observed that dragging the event to another date resulted in having the end date being start date + 1 day. So I changed my code to generate all day events with end date being start date + 1 day, which fixed the problem: now they appear on both the Web interface and the mobile app.
I guess something changed on the mobile app during a recent update.

Comment: I might be late... But your solution perfectly works for me, too. :-)